# Storing data into SQLite database crashes when click Add Item button

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, android-button

Whenever I click Add Item button my application crashes. Any ideas what going on ?
Is this how we implement a button call in android to submit data into SQLite database ?
Is there a way to hard code the values to test the insert if working ?

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText userName, tagNum, fabricColor, fabricType, itemComment;
SmartiWashDbAdapter smartiwashHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

    userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameValue);
    tagNum=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tagNumValue);
    fabricColor=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fabricColorValue);
    fabricType=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fabricTypeValue);
    itemComment=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentValue);

    smartiwashHelper= new SmartiWashDbAdapter(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Message.message(this, "Successfullly Iniatialized");
}

    public void addItem(View view){

        String addUser=userName.getText().toString();
        String addTag=tagNum.getText().toString();
        String addColor=fabricColor.getText().toString();
        String addType=fabricType.getText().toString();
        String addComment=itemComment.getText().toString();

        long id=smartiwashHelper.insertData(addUser, addTag, addColor, addType, addComment);

        if(id<0){
            Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
        }
        else {
            Message.message(this, "Successfullly Inserted");
        }
}
```

}

This is my fragment.xml. I called my button addItem in the XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/userNameValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/userName" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/tagNumValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/userNameValue"
    android:hint="@string/tagNumber" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/fabricColorValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tagNumValue"
    android:hint="@string/fabricColor" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/fabricTypeValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fabricColorValue"
    android:hint="@string/fabricType" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/commentValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fabricTypeValue"
    android:hint="@string/comment" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/commentValue"
    android:text="@string/addItem"
    android:onClick="addItem" />
```

This the logcat file. I am getting a NullExceptionPointer error. What does that mean ?

```
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17354)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    ... 11 more
04-06 03:29:25.525: E/AndroidRuntime(16166): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I fixed the problem moved the findById in the addItem method

```
public void addItem(View view){

        userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameValue);
        tagNum=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tagNumValue);
        fabricColor=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fabricColorValue);
        fabricType=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fabricTypeValue);
        itemComment=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentValue);

        String addUser=userName.getText().toString();
        String addTag=tagNum.getText().toString();
        String addColor=fabricColor.getText().toString();
        String addType=fabricType.getText().toString();
        String addComment=itemComment.getText().toString();


        long id=smartiwashHelper.insertData(addUser, addTag, addColor, addType, addComment);

        if(id<0){
            Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
        }
        else {
            Message.message(this, "Successfullly Inserted");
        }
}
```

Comment: which is your line no 32

Comment: How did this fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take id of the button.Here you have not taken any id of the button.And use onclicklistener accordingly.And call the additem function inside onclicklistener override function.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you give an example ? or link me to a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Create id for the Button in your xml file.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/commentValue"
    android:text="@string/addItem"
    android:onClick="addItem" />
```

And in your java file

```
Button but = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        additem(v);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I get this error now "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})"

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+SHIFT+O,IMPORT.And insert semicolon at required place

Comment: Where I should paste it exactly? inside onCreate ?

Comment: It crashes as soon as I open the app.

Comment: I posted the new logcat above. Look at it please .

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void addItem(View view){

        String addUser=userName.getText().toString();
        String addTag=tagNum.getText().toString();
        String addColor=fabricColor.getText().toString();
        String addType=fabricType.getText().toString();
        String addComment=itemComment.getText().toString();

        long id=smartiwashHelper.insertData(addUser, addTag, addColor, addType, addComment);

        if(id<0){
            Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
        }
        else {
            Message.message(this, "Successfullly Inserted");
        }
}
```

Copy this outside oncreate function.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you forgot to add activity in manifest file.And in java file you need to extend activity.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. What I should do then ? What do you mean by extend activity ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem moved the findById in the addItem method

public void addItem(View view){

```
    userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameValue);
    tagNum=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tagNumValue);
    fabricColor=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fabricColorValue);
    fabricType=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fabricTypeValue);
    itemComment=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentValue);

    String addUser=userName.getText().toString();
    String addTag=tagNum.getText().toString();
    String addColor=fabricColor.getText().toString();
    String addType=fabricType.getText().toString();
    String addComment=itemComment.getText().toString();


    long id=smartiwashHelper.insertData(addUser, addTag, addColor, addType, addComment);

    if(id<0){
        Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
    }
    else {
        Message.message(this, "Successfullly Inserted");
    }
```

}